# UDK problem with kismet and unreal code interfacing

Tags: ios, udk

Couple of questions that I really have looked for the answer to before posting.

I want to create enemies in a game (iOS - tower defense like) I am making them follow a path and do other things like die etc..

I created a simple piece of code to make a place-able enemy in my level but this is the thing I don't know what the best way to continue is. I want to create enemies in code rather than placing in game and therefore I do not know how to assign the kismet path to each one?

My mobile material isn't working even though I made the material have a mobile texture? Works in PC not in mobile preview.

Thanks in advance.
Mike

Class BlobzEnemyGround1 extends BlobzEnemy
placeable;

simulated function PostBeginPlay()
{
    super.PostBeginPlay();
    `log("Blobz Enemy Ground 1 spawned!");
}

defaultproperties
{
    bBlockActors=True
    bCollideActors=True

```
Begin Object Class=DynamicLightEnvironmentComponent Name=MyLightEnvironment
    bEnabled=TRUE
End Object
Components.Add(MyLightEnvironment)

Begin Object Class=StaticMeshComponent Name=PickupMesh
    StaticMesh=StaticMesh'UN_SimpleMeshes.TexPropCube_Dup'
    Materials(0)=Material'Level1.TestEnemyMat'
    LightEnvironment=MyLightEnvironment
    Scale3D=(X=0.25,Y=0.25,Z=0.5)
End Object
Components.Add(PickupMesh)

Begin Object Class=CylinderComponent Name=CollisionCylinder
    CollisionRadius=32.0
    CollisionHeight=64.0
    BlockNonZeroExtent=true
    BlockZeroExtent=true
    BlockActors=true
    CollideActors=true
End Object
CollisionComponent=CollisionCylinder
Components.Add(CollisionCylinder)
//bSupportedOnMobile=true;
```

}